# Where I made a mistake - FFmpeg (Linux) basic problem

Tags: ffmpeg

I just started learning FFmpeg. I have code (like below), but it's doing nothing.

```
fmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[intro1];
[1:v]trim=start=1:end=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[main1];
[1:v]trim=start=123.39:end=124.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[end1];
[intro1]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[intro1];
[end1]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[end1];
[intro1][main1][end1][output];
[a:1][audio]; -vcodec libx264 -map "[output]" -map"[audio]" "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You need to make sure to say what the code is supposed to be doing and what error you are getting (or how the output is wrong). Otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: Next time please copy and paste the complete log from the command.

Answer (score 1):

- `fmpeg` should be `ffmpeg`.
- You only have one input so `[1:v]` should be `[0:v]` (it starts counting from 0).
- No need for alpha for fading because you are not overlapping or blending frames.
- Ending fade needs to be a fade out (not fade in).
- You can't re-use filter output labels within the filtergraph.
- Some of your filterchains can be combined.
- Some of your labels are not associated with a filter (it appears you forgot to use the concat filter).
- You can add scale and setsar at the end instead of using them for each segment.
- Replace the last `;` with `"`.
- You didn't map the audio properly.
- Stream copy (re-mux) the audio.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:d=1[intro];[0:v]trim=start=1:end=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[main];[0:v]trim=start=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=out:d=1[end];[intro][main][end]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,scale=480x360,setsar=16/9[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```